# how to rename file in document library?

Tags: file-upload

I am using powershell to read a csv file and then uploading the file to sharepoint. However, I would like to rename the file. how is it done? Is it done before I load the file from fileshare to document library. or during the add method. I am not sure. Please let me know.

```
$sourceFile = Get-ChildItem $i.FileLocation
$newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($destinationFolderPath,$sourceFile.OpenRead(), $true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$theItem = $newFile.Item
$theItem["Name"] = $i.newfilename

where i is file stream and newfilename is the column name for new file name.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One other post here was answering something similar [upload file to document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39179/upload-file-to-document-library)

Pay attention to the last part when name is changed.